# Some websites (e.g box.com) use java to upload/download files which do not seem to honor my proxy settings. Is there a way to do it?

Tags: proxy, java-applet

The rest of the site does pass its traffic through the system proxy settings. Its this one event that uses java which seems to access internet directly.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use upstream hardware to proxy, no, an application chooses its proxies, not OS.

That said, you should be able to configure java to use a network proxy in the `configure Java` applet (search the start menu if you are in windows), under "Network Settings". If the applet you are running however specifically ignores the java and browser proxy settings however, you will not be able to force it to honor them unless you do so upstream.

Comment: I did check the 'configure Java' but that does not seem to work.

Comment: Can you elaborate on up-streaming hardware to proxy. Thanks